# Refactor during a feature implementation with mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial, legacy-code

I need advice on my development process with mercurial when working on legacy code.

When I'm developing a new feature for a legacy project, I often need to refactor a part of the existing code during a feature implementation. I mean, I didn't anticipated the refactoring and I need to do it *before* proceeding to the feature implementation since I'll use the refactored code.

Since I think the refactoring is valuable even if the feature is not implemented, I want it to be a changeset as itself, and not to be part of the "feature" changeset. Furthermore, since I work on legacy code, it is not well unit-tested, so I need to test (manually) the refactoring only, without the code of the feature being developed.

So, my current process when working of legacy code is the following:

1. work on the feature
2. oops, I need to refactor something, so
3. extract a patch from the current state of my working copy
4. revert the changes
5. do the refactoring and test!
6. commit a changeset to the mercurial repository
7. re-import the patch and deal with the conflicts manually
8. go back to 1.

Is there's something I could improve in my process with mercurial? Is there a way to save the working copy temporarily and get mercurial deal with the conflicts when putting back the saved changed in my working copy?

If not, does git address this use-case more than mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shelve` extension does steps 3, 4 and 7 for you.  Details can be found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension).

If you're using TortoiseHg, it is built in to the workbench in the Repository menu.

Comment: Interesting extension, I may be what I am looking for

Comment: There's also the `attic` extension that does a little more than `shelve`

Answer (score 2):

My small deviations

- I can't imagine own serious development without MQ, so

3 - save current work as MQ-patch

4 - qpop it

...

6 - commit in separate branch

7 - qpush on top of *refactoring branch*, resolve conflicts, qpop

7a - merge refactoring-branch into feature-branch

7b - qpush in feature-branch, resolve conflicts

7c - qfinish

Comment: I am not very familiar with MQ, so I guess I'll RTFM

Comment: +1 for MQ, but I'd do both the refactor and the new feature as patches (i.e. no commits) so I can move between working on the refactor and the feature as I need to. When you finish they both become separate commits. I do this a lot.

Comment: @PaulS - due to *stackable nature* of MQ-patches, I (and it's only my *style, not rule*) prefer don't have **dependent patches** in stack

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting a patch, I would commit the code:

1. Work on the feature
2. Discover you need to refactor something
3. **Commit your work in progress**
4. **Update to the revision before your commit**
5. Do the refactoring, test
6. **Commit the refactored code**
7. **Merge with the previously committed work in progress**
8. Continue, rinse, repeat

Bonus points if the work in progress you commit in step 3 is functional :), because broken code is a bad starting point to resume work after the refactor.

Comment: The problem is, I often have non-working code when I need to refactor, just because I need the refactored code in order to finish my feature.

Comment: Furthermore, I may decide that the implementation I'm working on is just so bad that I want to revert all my changes, so I'd have to backout the changeset.

Comment: Well it’s not terrible to check in non-working code (as long as you don’t push it), it’s just a better starting point to continue after the refactoring.

Comment: And if you want to revert all your changes you can just strip the changeset instead of merging it (just take care not to push it), or merge it but discard all changes.

Comment: I don't really like checking-in non-working code because it pollutes the history and make it harder to track the changes made for a single feature when you have a bug reported for that feature. So, I do my best to commit a feature as a single changeset when possible

Comment: In that case, instead of merging the changeset in step 7 you can rebase it; then it lives on top of the refactoring, and you will be able to amend it in various ways. For example by replaying the changes into a new commit after stripping the old one with `hg strip --keep`.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm in this situation, I do everything in one large lump, and when I'm ready to commit, I pick the patch apart either using `qrecord` or by hand (using Emacs).

Comment: What if both the refactoring and the feature affect the same file?

Comment: Then some additional work is required ;). In my experience, this does happen, but it rarely affects more than a hunk or two.